# Can I force YARN to use the master node for the Application Master container?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, elastic-map-reduce

My big ol' master node hardware is doing practically nothing during my Hadoop/Spark runs because YARN uses a random slave node for its AM on each task.  I like the old Hadoop 1 way better; lots of log chasing and ssh pain was avoided that way when things went wrong.

Is it possible?

Comment: technically YARN api has methods for these manipulations, like this one https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/api/records/ApplicationSubmissionContext.html#setAMContainerResourceRequest(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ResourceRequest)

Comment: but I've never seen any simple hadoop example to understand how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with Spark and YARN node labels.

1. Labelize your nodes
2. Use `spark.yarn.am.nodeLabelExpression`
   properties

Good to read:

- https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/2017/03/10/yarn-node-labels/